# Не получается установить библиотеку distutils

Tags: python

Мне необходимо установить библиотеку *distutils*, 
когда ввожу команду:

```
pip install distutils
```

выдает ошибку:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement distutils (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for distutils

при этом *pip* обновлен до последней версии, надеюсь на помощь.

Comment: distutils это встроенная библиотека, её не нужно устанавливать. И она устарела и была удалена в Python 3.12